# Add Loading Icon to GridView Row whilst results are loading. WEBFORMS c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

```
public partial class ConnectionStatus : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            PullData();
        }
    }
    public void PullData()
    {
        string SQLRET = "SELECT RX_ID, ShopID, Primary_IP, ServiceType, Hardware FROM RouterHealthCheck";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLRET, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dt.Columns.Add("Results", typeof(string));

        //iterate the rows and ping each IP. Additionaly you can also code to ignore repeating IP
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Columns[0].Table.Rows)
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(dr["Primary_IP"].ToString());

            if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                dr["Results"] = string.Format("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                dr["Results"] = string.Format("Offline");
            }
        }

        GridViewRouters.DataSource = dt;
        GridViewRouters.DataBind();
 }
```

I have a GridView that is taking IP Addresses and pinging them and posting results.  The page is taking too long to load. I was wondering if it's at all possible to stick a loading icon in the Results column whilst the data is loading and then refresh it with "Success" or "Error" once it's done.

Comment: What you are asking for is an asynchronous update. Look into SignalR if you need to push data to WebPage.  Or you could try [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: Can you offer up a example code? i've done some research and this looks like the correct way to go about it.

Comment: there is an example and complete description on how to implement this on  the link I included